# web-service method returning a System.Drawing.Image instance. Any encoding needed?

Tags: c#, web-services, image

i have a web-service that will be returning a collection of System.Drawing.Image objects. My question is that can I directly send back a System.Drawing.Image instance from a web-service (given that this class implements ISerializable interface) or will I have to apply some type of encoding to it?

Comment: Are you still using old ASMX web services?

Comment: FYI, in general, `ISerializable` or the `[Serializable]` attribute are not used in XML Serialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to encode it. The response type of web services can be non-text, but typically consists of XML or JSON with a text payload.

You can encode your image as Base64, this can turn any binary into text. See also http://www.dailycoding.com/Posts/convert_image_to_base64_string_and_base64_string_to_image.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the System.Data.Linq.Binary class send the data back and forth over a WCF service as well.  I used that because it didn't require any extra work on the server side when storing it in an SQL Server database.  Although there was a little extra work on the silverlight side to convert it back into a usable format.  (Just a few lines of code.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WCF, you can send it as a stream as well.